# Redux dispatch before rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to dispatch an action before the component is rendered.
But the action is an async action integrated with redux-saga.

I have to know when is the async action is done, if it is done, then render the component.
To make this work, I have a unique id for each container and after the action done, the attribute { loaded: true } would be saved into store.

I am thinking of this way

```
@preload('uniqueId', (dispatch) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  dispatch(MyAction(resolve, reject));
})
@connect(....)
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ....
}
```

`@preload` is a function trigger the specified action in `componenWillMount` (For server side) or `componenDidMount` (For client side) and when the action call `resolve()`, the `state.preloadState.uniqueId.loaded` will set to `true`. It also wrap the component so that only render the component when `state.preloadState.uniqueId.loaded === true`.

`@connect` connect the data I wanna preloaded into redux store in the specified action.

I wonder if it is common practice to do data preload for redux, redux-saga app and also for server-side rendering (I have used redux-async-connect before, but I wanna make all nested component able to do the data preload so I bind to componentWillMount instead of some static function).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can't really stop a component from rendering (without having its parent simply not render it), but you can conditionally render nothing. Something like:

```
render() {
  if (!state.data) { return null; }
  return <div>{state.data}</div>
}
```